# Typescript Generic Class Constructor Argument with static methods

Tags: typescript, generics

So the basic problem I have is this.

I have a base class from which all other classes are derived.  It has a static method.  Something like this:

```
class BaseClass {
  static blah() : string {
    return 'base';
  }
}

class OtherClass extends BaseClass {
  static blah() : string {
    return 'other';
  }
}

class DoesntExtend extends SomeOtherClass {

}
```

Then I have a function which I want to pass in the Class Constructor and call the static method, but I'm having trouble with the method signature.

I want to use it something like this:

```
console.log(funcCaller(BaseClass)) -> outputs 'base'
console.log(funcCaller(OtherClass)) -> outputs 'other'
console.log(funcCaller(DoesntExtend)) -> won't compile, since DoesntExtend won't have the static method
```

So I thought to do something like:

```
type Constructor<T extends BaseClass > = new(...args: any[]) => T;

function funcCaller<T extends BaseClass>(c : Constructor<T>) : string {
  return c.blah();
}
```

but tsc complains that

```
Property 'blah' does not exist on type 'Constructor'
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `funcCaller` function needs to accept `typeof` the class to access the static properties. This is because static properties exist on the type while the signature you have used accepts an instance of that type. [As the docs says](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html), "To refer to the *type* that the value f has, we use `typeof`".

[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/RwRKxN)

```ts
class BaseClass {
  static blah() : string {
    return 'base';
  }
}

class OtherClass extends BaseClass {
  static blah() : string {
    return 'other';
  }
}

class DoesntOverride extends BaseClass{

}

class SomeOtherClass {
}

class DoesntExtend extends SomeOtherClass {

}

function funcCaller(c : typeof BaseClass) : string {
    return c.blah();
}

// base
console.log(funcCaller(BaseClass));

// other
console.log(funcCaller(OtherClass));

// base
console.log(funcCaller(DoesntOverride));

// Shows error
console.log(funcCaller(DoesntExtend));
```

Comment: Wow thanks, didn't even know you could use typeof like that,

Comment: Great, this code works and solves a similar problem for me!  The description is, however, incorrect - the code as written in the OP does not accept an _instance_ of the type (e.g. `funcCaller(new OtherClass())` will generate an error), but only constructors that derive from BaseClass, which is almost exactly the same set of things that `typeof BaseClass` accepts (except, the latter, I guess, somehow pulls along the whole class's type, not just the constructor's signature itself, not that there's actually any difference in the underlying JS ^_^).